# Error after installing extension , Unable to access configuration in store, Mageplaza Extension

Tags: magento2, error, extensions, third-party-module

> Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   /home/208806.cloudwaysapps.com/mnaanucsmd/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php
>   on line 63

Error log record number: 1370744923540.

Got this error after trying to install a new module/extension mageplaza SMTP extension.

My iterator.php

```
public function setElements(array $elements, $scope)
    {
        $this->_elements = $elements;
        $this->_scope = $scope;
        if (count($elements)) {
            $lastElement = end($elements);
            $this->_lastId = $lastElement['id']; //<--- Line 63 is here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check that `Mageplaza_Core` module installed and enabled.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau how do i do that i am quite a newbie..

Comment: I have written detailed answer. Please, check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that Mageplaza_Core module installed and enabled:

From the Magento root directory type:

```
php bin/magento module:status Mageplaza_Core
```

You should see something like:

> Module is enabled

In case you seeing something other you should install it (type from the Magento root directory):

```
composer require mageplaza/module-core
```

then enable it:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Mageplaza_Core
```

*Note: On my server it looks like this:*

[image: example]

and make update:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

update static files if needed:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

After that it should work as expected.

*Note: do not forget to run all commands from the correspondent web-server's user to avoid permissions issue.*

Comment: works like a charm :) thnx alot